# How to know whether iOS open wifi or not？

Tags: ios, wifi

I just want to know if the wifi is switch on, because my app just want users switch on the wifi button, they don't need to connect a wifi at all..
but i just cant get the message whether user have already switch the wifi on..

Comment: What you mean by this "my app just want users switch on the wifi button, they don't need to connect a wifi at all". Actually what are you trying to implement?.

Comment: @Nitheesh George I just want to know  whether  the mobile wifi is open, if have not available wifi it just open but not connected@greg-449

Answer (score 0):

Use Rechability class,which is a drop-in replacement for Apple's Reachability class. It is ARC-compatible, and it uses the new GCD methods to notify of network interface changes.

Once download and check the below link.

[Download Rechability from here](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability)

Answer (score 0):

To check internet connectivity use the following code

```
Reachability *networkReachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
NetworkStatus networkStatus = [networkReachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
    NSLog(@"Internet connection available");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Internet connection not available");
}
```

Check the sample code from Apple [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_7)

Comment: I want to know whether wifi is enabled  like this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744658/detect-wifi-enabled-regardless-of-whether-its-connected?rq=1

Comment: Then use the method in reachability [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:(NSString *)hostName]; to check www.google.com is reachable. if so you connected to internet.