# Better way to detect WiFi enabled/disabled on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, wifi

After an unbelievable amount of teeth gnashing, I finally have a method that successfully detects if WiFi is enabled on iOS independent of whether it's connected or not.  There are at least a couple uses for such a thing, and I don't think this violates the spirit or the letter of Apple Law(tm).

However, it's ugly and probably won't work forever.  It currently works on iOS 10.2.1, as of Jan 31, 2017.  I'll put my answer below and hope that someone can improve it.  I've heavily researched Reachability (*doesn't meet the requirements*), CaptiveNetwork, HotspotHelper, SCNetworkConfiguration, Xamarin's System.Net.NetworkInterface, and more.  This is it that actually works as far as I can tell.

Comment: CaptiveNetwork, btw, is useful for determining if the device *has* WiFi:         public bool DeviceHasWifi()
        {
            string[] sifa;
            CaptiveNetwork.TryGetSupportedInterfaces(out sifa);
            
            // if there's at least one interface that supports captive networks, then it has WiFi
            return (0 != sifa.Length);
        }

Comment: There is never any need for anything like that. If your application wants WIFI, just write it on your app description or a help page in your app. It's not your job to check the type of the network.

Comment: While I agree that *most* apps don't need such a thing, your generalization to "never" is unwarranted

Comment: I still insisted never. If your app can't connect without Wifi, just show connection error and a help page. There is never any application for checking WIFI against Internet.

Comment: I have a use case that I isn't the simplistic common scenario you refer to and I guarantee you're not thinking of, and in *doing actual research on this problem* I've come across others.

Answer (score 2):

The gist of the solution is that when there's TWO interfaces reported by getifaddrs() with the name "awdl0" then WiFi is enabled.  Just one and it's disabled.

I credit pebble8888 for pointing me to https://github.com/alirp88/SMTWiFiStatus which is Objective-C, where the lack of comments make it hard to understand what's going on or what the author's intention was.

Here's my full and complete Xamarin/C# solution, which ought to be pretty readable for any other major language user:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Beacon.iOS
{
/// <summary>
/// code stolen from the Xamarin source code to work around goofy interactions between
/// the good-god-why-would-it-work-that-way iOS and the entirely reasonable Xamarin
/// (it doesn't report interfaces that are reported multiple times)
/// </summary>
class XamHack
{
    //
    // Types
    //
    internal struct ifaddrs
    {
#pragma warning disable 0649
        public IntPtr ifa_next;
        public string ifa_name;
        public uint ifa_flags;
        public IntPtr ifa_addr;
        public IntPtr ifa_netmask;
        public IntPtr ifa_dstaddr;
        public IntPtr ifa_data;
#pragma warning restore
    }

    //
    // OS methods
    //
    [DllImport("libc")]
    protected static extern int getifaddrs(out IntPtr ifap);

    [DllImport("libc")]
    protected static extern void freeifaddrs(IntPtr ifap);


    //
    // Methods
    //

    /// <summary>
    /// Our glorious hack.  I apologize to the programming gods for my sins
    /// but this works (for now) and functionality trumps elegance.  Even this.
    /// Reverse engineered from: https://github.com/alirp88/SMTWiFiStatus
    /// </summary>
    public static bool IsWifiEnabled()
    {
        int count = 0;
        IntPtr ifap;

        // get the OS to put info about all the NICs into a linked list of buffers
        if (getifaddrs(out ifap) != 0)
            throw new SystemException("getifaddrs() failed");

        try
        {
            // iterate throug those buffers
            IntPtr next = ifap;
            while (next != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                // marshall the data into our struct
                ifaddrs addr = (ifaddrs)Marshal.PtrToStructure(next, typeof(ifaddrs));

                // count the instances of the sacred interface name
                if ("awdl0" == addr.ifa_name)
                    count++;

                // move on to the next interface
                next = addr.ifa_next;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // leaking memory is for jerks
            freeifaddrs(ifap);
        }

        // if there's two of the sacred interface, that means WiFi is enabled.  Seriously.
        return (2 == count);
    }

} // class
} // namespace
```

Comment: Ok, well all I can say is it still works for me in all cases on all devices, as well as all the users of my app.  Perhaps more specificity?

Comment: I tested it in my both iPhong7P and iPhone8, they are all iOS11. what device/version did you test?

Comment: I've personally tested a 6s on iOS 10, but a teammate has run iOS 11 and we've got a lot of users running both OSes, too, and we've never seen a complain here.  This would be a major disruption of functionality, so I'm sure we would hear about it.  You're not running on the simulator are you?  Have you stepped through the code and checked the properties of the objects it's iterating over?

Comment: Hi Eliot, Actually I haven't tested your C# code. But I tested both Swift and Objective-C code, which I believe they have the same logic to check WiFi status by "awdl0".  And I can get 2 "awdl0"(typo in my first reply. It is 2) whatever WiFi is ON or OFF.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the detail. My personal iOS 11 device doesn't arrive for 2 more weeks, so I can't trace it myself, sorry.  I did check that our code hasn't changed from the above, and that we do have a lot of users on iOS 11.  If it weren't for those, I'd suggest looking at the flags to see if the enabled bit varies between the two states.

Comment: Hi Eliot, is it possible for me to download your app on my iPhone? In that case, I can check if it works with my iOS devices. Thanks

Comment: Oh, good idea!  Our app is called AirFlare and it's available from both app stores.  We do unusual stuff because we use WiFi to locate people missing in the wilderness using their mobile phone.

Comment: Thanks, I installed your App. It always showed "WiFi Enabled" whatever the WiFi was toggled ON/OFF. Was it supposed to be like this? https://youtu.be/MIDcjF-PQAA

Comment: Sorry, you have the buy the subscription before the beacon can be installed, which is required before it tells you whether WiFi is enabled or not. You can buy and then get it refunded though, I think.

Comment: Where can I buy the specific beacon? or any beacon is OK?

Comment: Just hit the Upgrade button and hit Subscribe. Should be pretty straightfoward (if not, we have other problems!).

Comment: I tried to upgrade but unfortunately my credit card(not US card) is not accepted by AppStore. Is it possible to download it from Testflight?

Comment: I KNOW WHAT IT IS.  You're using the Command Center to flip WiFi off, no?  Well, in iOS 11, that's only "soft off."  Temporary.  It'll turn it self back on by the next morning.  "Hard off" only happens when turning off via Settings app.  That's what we detect, still successfully, but we don't have code for soft off yet.

Comment: Thanks, @Eliot Gillum, you are right. It works with "Hard off", not "soft off"